# Npm and Node commands are broken

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, fedora

Every time I try and run `npm -v` or `node -v` I get:

```
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
```

This is my /usr/local/bin/

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     492 Jun 13 15:23 bundle
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root     493 Jun 13 15:23 bundler
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root    2774 Jan 25  2015 charm
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 1116534 Aug  7  2015 composer
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root    2777 Jul 23  2015 mine
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      15 Oct 13 14:44 node -> /usr/bin/nodejs
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      38 Oct 13 14:53 npm -> ../lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root      20 Jan 21  2016 packettracer -> /opt/pt/packettracer
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root    2580 Jan 25  2015 pstorm
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  255192 Apr 11  2016 rdesktop
-rw-r--r--  1 root root     165 Jan 27  2015 subl
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  193370 Aug  7  2015 symfony
```

If I navigate to the following directory, I can see npm and node in there and I can check the versions without error

```
/usr/local/n/versions/node/6.6.0/bin
```

Also when I try and run sudo yum install nodejs, it tells me it's already installed and that i'm running an older version. This all happened after I recently updated node and npm.

Comment: Post the output of `echo $PATH`, `which node` and `which nodejs`

Comment: Both which node and which nodejs both gave the same error as npm -v. I fixed this problem though. I uninstalled node and reinstalled it and everything started working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems very likely that this didn't work because the `node` binary is in `/usr/local/n/versions/node/6.6.0/bin` (as you say) and that isn't in the `PATH` environment variable. By default, this is set to some of the standard locations for binaries, and this isn't one of those, so `env` has no idea where to look. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26047/how-to-correctly-add-a-path-to-path for more on setting this.